# Continuous color through multiple plots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]This is a plot of carbon (y1985 etc) against distance (st).

I am trying to plot changes in a parameter over time with color ...therefore I would like to have a continuous color gradient going through all the plots for instance light blue to dark blue which represent 1985-2018. Or 'jet' colormap running through.. Is this possible?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1985'],c='lightskyblue')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1986'],c='lightskyblue')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1987'],c='cornflowerblue')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1988'],c='cornflowerblue')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1989'],c='steelblue')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1990'],c='steelblue')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1991'],c='royalblue')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1992'],c='royalblue')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1993'],c='navy')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1994'],c='navy')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1995'],c='lightgreen')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1996'],c='lightgreen')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1997'],c='mediumseagreen')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1998'],c='mediumseagreen')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y1999'],c='seagreen')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2000'],c='seagreen')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2001'],c='green')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2002'],c='green')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2003'],c='darkgreen')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2004'],c='darkgreen')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2005'],c='lightsalmon')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2006'],c='lightsalmon')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2007'],c='darksalmon')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2008'],c='darksalmon')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2009'],c='coral')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2010'],c='coral')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2011'],c='orangered')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2012'],c='orangered')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2013'],c='maroon')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2014'],c='maroon')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2015'],c='mediumpurple')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2016'],c='mediumpurple')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2017'],c='rebeccapurple')
ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc['y2018'],c='rebeccapurple')
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I guess your looking for something like this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

Comment: Can you share some part of your data as @Ruthger defined dfc

Comment: @lourew: Hi, did the answers help you? It would help the SO community to give feedback or cast your votes / accepted answers!

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay I have had some other technical issues - I can not seem to share the excel spreadsheet so I shared an image thanks! - sorry again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Example data:

```
dfc = pd.DataFrame({'st':[1,2,3,4,5], 'y1985':[2,4,6,7,8], 'y1986':[4,5,6,7,10], 'y1987':[7,9,11,12,15]})
```

The data is in wide format, for Matplotlib the long format would fit better. For this we can use `pd.melt`:

```
ndfc = pd.melt(dfc, id_vars = ['st'])
```

We then need to recode the time data with a sequence:

```
ndfc['code'] = pd.factorize(ndfc['variable'])[0]
```

The plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(ndfc['st'],ndfc['value'],c=ndfc['code'], cmap="jet_r")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but this changes color with distance (x axis), I would like to change the colour between each year i.e. y1985 and y1986 etc. therefore each ax.scatter plot :)

Comment: Then can you try to replace the `dfc['st'],dfc['y1985']` like `ax.scatter(dfc['y1985'], dfc['st'], c=dfc['t'], cmap="jet_r")`

Comment: @lourew: I have now changed it to year as factor. I have changed the data from wide to long format which makes it a lot easier in Matplotlib. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi sorry! my python/anaconda had issues so I am back to it will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Hi I am not sure how this fits with my data, once again sorry for the delayed response

Comment: @lourew, I see that you added a printscreen of Excel data to the question. However, I do not see any difference with the example that I used in the answer. Could you tell what kind of error you received when running my code?

Comment: Hey, so after putting in the following code  ```ndfc = pd.melt(dfc, id_vars = ['st']), ndfc['code'] = pd.factorize(ndfc['variable'])[0], fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(ndfc['st'],ndfc['value'],c=ndfc['code'], cmap="jet_r")``` I get ```
  File "C:\Users\Rewrie\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py", line 218, in update
    raise TypeError("{val!r} is not a string".format(val=val))

TypeError: 2406.884598209218 is not a string```

Comment: Could you see what is the data type using both `dfc.dtypes` and `ndfc.dtypes` ? What is the Matplotlib version, `matplotlib.__version__` ?

Comment: @lourew: It's my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [this example plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-polar-scatter-py) it creates a random array for colors:

```
...
theta = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(N)
colors = theta
...
c = ax.scatter(theta, r, c=colors, s=area, cmap='hsv', alpha=0.75)
```

Since I don't have any idea about your data, i give you an approximated answer:

```
import numpy as np

years = ['y' + str(i) for i in range(1985, 2019)]
len_years = len(years)
colors = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(len_years)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for idx, year in enumerate(years):
  ax.scatter(dfc['st'],dfc[year], c=colors[idx])
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi thanks for this! I do not yet understand this code so I will have to go through it as I ran it and it didn't work.. I am not sure how the years applies to my data set. Each y1985 etc refers to a column header... thanks again:)

Comment: `years = ['y' + str(i) for i in range(1985, 2019)]` creates a list of your columns like `['y1985', '1986', '1987' ...]` . If you share your data i can give you a code snippet that runs

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay I have had some other technical issues - I can not seem to share the excel spreadsheet so I shared an image thanks! - sorry again!